# Indexing problem in sections using titlesec

Tags: indexing, titlesec

My probşem is pretty simple but I could not solve the problem. I use the titlesec to modify the font and bold of my section, subsection and subsubsection but this is kinda messed up the indexing of the sections. What I want is:
1.First Section
1.1 First subsection
1.1.1 First subsubsection

But it only gives me an output of 
1.First section
1.first subsection

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{20}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

Comment: You are using `\thesection` in every `\titleformat`. You should use `\thesection` `\thesubsection` etc. accordingly to what you are defining.

Comment: This solves the problem. Thanks a lot. How I miss that point.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `\thesection` in every `\titleformat`. You should use `\thesection` `\thesubsection` etc. accordingly to what you are defining.

So this is how your definitions should look like:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{20}{15}\bfseries}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{14}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\fontsize{12}{15}\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will point you in the right direction--when i change the \section I do it the following way using

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}%<-------------in the preamble
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}%<-----------------in the preamble

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\uline{SECTION~\thesection :}}{0em} 
{\uline{\MakeUppercase{\hspace*{1em}   #1}}}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}
```

Now when I use it in the following manner

```
\section{professional competence}
```

my output is

[image]

Now if I want to change the subsection I use

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection~\Alph{subsection}}
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]
{\normalfont\bfseries}{\uline{\thesubsection :}}{0em}{\uline{{\hspace*{1em}   #1}}}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{24pt}{12pt}
```

and use it like

```
 \subsection{Annual workplan and achievements}
```

and my output is

[image]